# Text box in form contains data but does not save to underlying table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am creating an ms-Access 2007 form to save results of multiple evaluations of a single product "Batch". I was able to create a pair of combo boxes that look up the list of possible batches, both criteria ("Item" and "QCN") are primary keys in the "BatchInfo" table and the row source pulls these from the table for both combo boxes using "SELECT DISTINCTROW". I have two text boxes bound to different columns of a query on the "BatchInfo" table, one from each combo box. They appear to work together correctly, except the data displayed in the QCN text box is not correct. 
I'm testing this all with a "New Record" button on the form, which runs the following code:

```
Sub btnNewRecord_Click()
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
End Sub
```

The rest is not in VBA, so I'm not sure how to explain it most succinctly here, but let's see if this works: ("Display" means after I have selected a batch from the cmbItem combo box)

cmbItem   Control Source  is  Item; Bound column 1; Column Count 2; Column Widths 1”,0.5”; Displays Item; 
txtItem displays “Item” and Saves “Item” to table correctly

cmbQCN Control Source is Item; Bound column 2; Column Count 2; Column Widths 0”,1”; Displays Item instead of QCN; 
txtQCN displays "Item" instead of "QCN", but appears to be blank when saving record to table.

Row Source for both combo boxes is:
SELECT DISTINCTROW qryBatchesBySiteByDate.Item, qryBatchesBySiteByDate.QCNumber FROM qryBatchesBySiteByDate;

qryBatchesBySiteByDate pulls Item and QCN from BatchInfo and connects them to a production location.

Changing one thing at a time:

-Change bound column of cmbQCN to 1; now combo displays desired value but doesn't pass it to the text box.

cmbItem   Control Source  is  Item; Bound column 1; Column Count 2; Column Widths 1”,0.5”; Displays Item; 
txtItem displays “Item” and Saves “Item” to table correctly

cmbQCN Control Source is Item; Bound column 2; Column Count 2; Column Widths 0”,1”; Displays Item instead of QCN; 
txtQCN displays "QCN" correctly, but appears to be blank when saving record to table.

-Change Control Source of cmbQCN to QCN; now combo boxes don't work together

cmbItem   Control Source  is  Item; Bound column 1; Column Count 2; Column Widths 1”,0.5”; Displays Item; 
txtItem displays “Item” and Saves “Item” to table correctly

cmbQCN Control Source is cmbQCN; Bound column 2; Column Count 2; Column Widths 0”,1”; Display is blank; 
txtQCN is blank, and appears to be blank when saving record to table.

I think I have at least two problems:
1. Even if txtQCN displays data, that data does not write to the table when I save the record;
2. txtQCN is displaying Item instead of QCN even when cmbQCN displays QCN correctly.

I thought maybe there was an issue with the relationships since both Item and QCN are Primary Keys in BatchInfo but doesn't the query maintain the relationships?

I'm hoping I'm just missing a setting somewhere but I can't figure out what it could be.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say "both Item and QCN are Primary Keys in BatchInfo", do you mean that in table design view both of these fields have the key symbol against them? This is known as a 'composite primary key' (you can't have two primary keys). Next question - what is the Control Source set to for txtItem and txtQCN? And what is the Record Source for the form. Can you post more details of your table structure including relationships?

Comment: Yes, that describes the Primary Key situation, so I learned a new term! It is a composite primary key. Control sources for txtItem and txtQCN are Item and QCN respectively. I have been working on it and gave up on the second combo box when I figured out I could use the following code in the AfterUpdate property of cmbItem to make it work:  
    Me.QCN = [cmbItem].[Column](1)
Thanks!